# RedirectMatch except certain files (css|js|jpg|png|etc)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all files except those in whitelist to 404 page.. but I
can't find a way to add something like RewriteCond to my current htaccess code:

`RedirectMatch 404 ^.*$`

Now i want to add something like

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|jpg|js|png)$`

though i know `RewriteCond` is only for `RewriteRule`

can someone please help me?

So the question is, how can I achieve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex in the RedirectMatch statement should work for you:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^.*\.(?!(js|html|gif)).*$
```

The stuff inside the brackets after ?! is your whitelist. Every file extension not named here will lead to 404.

Comment: cool! thanks. but i don't get why you need a `.*$` after the whitelist.. isn't $ supposed to mean it is the last part of the expression? so a "test.js[.* here]$" is different from plain "test.js$".. i tested it on a regex tool and it doesn't work like what I thought it would be. Instead, it worked as what my original question was looking for. weird. >.<

Comment: the `^` in the beginning matches the beginning of the string. After, the `.*` will match zero or unlimited amount of characters, until the dot, which is `\.`. Then we exclude after the points js, html and gif with `(?!(js|html|gif))`. The `.*` will match anything else after the dot, for example .php, .png, etc.

Comment: aah ok. so the whole subset is `(?!(js|html|gif)).*`, i thought it was  `(?!(js|html|gif))` and `.*` which would mean anything after the dot, then `.*` which i was confused. i thought it wasn't needed but it is. thanks!